# Opencv solve throws cv::Exception

Tags: c++, linear-regression, opencv3.0

On Windows 10, running Visual Studio 2015.  Opencv 3.0

Using Opencv to first correlate two images and determine translation between them using matchTemplate.  I want to get subpixel estimate so I am going to input an 11X11 window of values from the correlation output and fit a quadratic surface to those points.

```
void Sector1::ResampSector(cv::Mat In, cv::Mat R, cv::Mat Out, cv::Point Loc)
{
// first get fractional offset
int lsq = 5; 
// Ax^2 + B xy + Cy^2 + Dx +Ey + F = R
cv::setBreakOnError(true);
cv::Mat A( 121, 6, CV_32F);
cv::Mat B( 121, 1, CV_32F);
cv::Mat C (6, 1, CV_32F);
int L = 0;
for (int i = Loc.y-lsq; i <= Loc.y+lsq; i++) {
    for (int j = Loc.x-lsq; j <= Loc.x+lsq; j++) {
        A.at<float>(L, 0) = float(i*i);
        A.at<float>(L, 1) = (float)i*j;
        A.at<float>(L, 2) = (float)j*j;
        A.at<float>(L, 3) = (float)i;
        A.at<float>(L, 4) = (float)j;
        A.at<float>(L, 5) = 1.f;
        B.at<float>(L)    = R.at<float>(i, j); // since is 3 band stuff ?
        L++;
    }  // for j
}  // for i
bool rc = cv::solve(A, B, C);
```

the call to cv::solve returns false and there are two cv::Exceptions at same address which is outside of any of the image matrices or other variables.  I have looked at the contents of A, B and C using memory window and they all appear correct.  A,B,C structures all appear correct.  I have tried to step into solve but i do not have the library with symbolic tables.

Any clue where i have gone wrong?  suggestions for further tracking the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lapack complains that the default method will not work.  correction is to add the flag=DECOMP_QR as the 4th, optional, arguement to the call to solve()